# Back browser validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have simple application in codeigniter. I have login and logout in it. When I logged in.[image]

**member** page is opened as in below screenshot. But when I click on back browser as arrow indicate, then it goes to **login** page. similar is the case when I logged out, **login** page is opened, but when I clicked on back browser as arrow indicate in below screenshot, then it goes to **member** page.[image]

I want to validate it. I means it should be only in **login** page or **member** page, when I don't logged out or I don't logged in. when I press **back** browser arrow.

Session is used for this, or something else, but I don't know should I do it. Proper code for it is needed. Please help me friends. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us, how you have controlled the session veriable in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use session in login controller

See below code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
         redirect('login');
    }

}
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Thanks for update, it's work for me because when we back to previous page first constructor call and check either login or not.If not then it redirect to login page.

Answer (score 2):

You should make session control in login controller. You can use the code below:

```
if (!$this->session->userdata())
{
  //put your login controller content here
}
else
{
  redirect('your_dashboard_url');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use session in codeigniter.check below link

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session

Answer (score 0):

I try the following code,but still page is go back.

```
public function members()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/members');

    }
    else
    {
        redirect('main/login');
    }

}
```

main is the controller's name and login and members are functions.